# Numpy Array Conditional Operation Mask?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose you have an array:

`a = 
     [ 0,1,0]
     [-1,2,1]
     [3,-4,2]`

And lets say you add 20 to everything

`b = 
      [  20,  21, 20]
      [  19,  22, 21]
      [  23,  16, 22]`

Now lets say I want to add the resulting `b` to the original array `a` but only in cases where `a < 0` i.e at the index `[0,1]` and `[1,2]` where `a = -1, -4` respectively *getting the value 0 otherwise*. Ultimately leading to a matrix as such:

`c = 
     [ 0,  0, 0]
     [ 18, 0, 0] 
     [ 0, 12, 0]`


     `18 = 19 (from b) + -1 (from a)
     12 = 16 (from b) + -4 (from a)`

And assume that I want to be able to extend this to any operation (not just add 20), so that you can't just filter all values < 20 from matrix `c`. So I want to use matrix `a` as a mask toward matrix c, zeroing the `i, j` where `a[i,j] < 0`.

I'm having a tough time finding a concise example of how to do this in numpy with python. I was hoping you may be able to direct me to the correct implementation of such a method.

What I am struggling to get is this into a mask and only performing operations on the retained values, finally resulting in `c`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
(a + b)*(a<0)
```

should work unless you have very strong requirements concerning the number of intermediate arrays.

Comment: very elegant solution!

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. I can't imagine someone has a more clean method. Very cleanly executed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through a combination of [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) and [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Working example below,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 0,1,0],[-1,2,1],[3,-4,2]])
b = a+20
c = np.zeros(a.shape)
c[a<0] = b[a<0] + a[a<0]
```

which gives `c` as

```
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 18.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  12.,   0.]])
```

The only important line in the code snippet above is the last one. Because the entries of `a`, `b`, and `c` are all aligned, we can say we want only the corresponding indices of `c` where `a<0` to be assigned to the sum of the entries in `b` and `a` where `a<0`.

Comment: This is good, but not as elegant as Thomas's solution. Thanks for the links and attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the same result:

```
c = np.where(a < 0, a + b, 0)
```

Although this is slightly more verbose than [Thomas Baruchel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709382/9171260), I found the method signature similar to the ternary operation (`a < 0 ? a + b : 0`), which makes it easier for me to understand what it is doing right away. Also, this is still a one-liner which makes it elegant enough in my opinion.

reference: [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the cleanest solution, but how about this?:

```
def my_mask(a, b, threshold=0):
    c = numpy.zeros(a.shape)
    idx = np.where(a < threshold)
    for ii in idx:
        c[ii[1], ii[0]] = a[ii[1], ii[0]] + b[ii[1], ii[0]]
    return c
```

Comment: For loops should really be avoided when dealing with NumPy arrays unless the desired operation cannot be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `numpy.zeros_like` function:

```
import numpy as np

# the initial array
a = [[ 0,1,0],
     [-1,2,1],
     [3,-4,2]]

a = np.array(a)
b = a + 20                         # after adding 20 to each element
c = np.zeros_like(a)               # resulting matrix (filled with zeros by default)
neg = a < 0                        # indeces of negative values
c[neg] = b[neg] + a[neg]           # overriding the needed elements

print(c)
```

The output:

```
[[ 0  0  0]
 [18  0  0]
 [ 0 12  0]]
```